# MAC osx, change datadir mysql, still not working

Tags: java, mysql

Hi i am tearing my hair out at this one, i am a noob ill admit when it comes to mysql, i had ir working perfectly on my local Mac HD, i now want to store the databse to my external as the databse could be 100gb,

Mac osx does not seem to have my.cnf as default in /etc location, so i grabed one "my-huge.cnf" ranmed it and stored it in this folder, i now added the datadir = my/new/location
under the field [mysqld] which also contains information such as port and socket,

I also ran `cp -R -p /etc/mysql/data /Volumes/Elements/database`
to copy my old databse values to the new one, i then changed
`datadir = /Volumes/Elements/database`

now my database wont work,
i tried to restart mysqld, im getting

```
101130 15:13:11 [Warning] '--skip-locking' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--skip-external-locking' instead.
101130 15:13:11 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Volumes/Elements/database/ is case insensitive
101130 15:13:11 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
101130 15:13:11 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
101130 15:13:11  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
mysqld: Too many arguments (first extra is 'restart').
Use --verbose --help to get a list of available options
101130 15:13:11 [ERROR] Aborting

101130 15:13:11  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
101130 15:13:17  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
101130 15:13:17 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

When i try and access the database "through my java program in eclipse"
i now get
"the last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."

Im officially at a complete loss

Also i think the issue might be with the socket, as when i type mysql in the terminal i get

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to symlink your old MySQL data directory to the new location.

`ln -s /Volumes/Elements/database /etc/mysql/data`

Comment: thanks but solution doesnt work, id like to know how to change the my.cnf file correctly?

Comment: Ok its only when i add the Datadir field in i get these problems, under [mysqld] field